# FUSE buffer size?

Tags: c, fuse

So I am trying to copy a string to the fuse buffer. When I try to call sizeof(buf) I get an error and my program crashes. My problem is that I believe I am reaching the maximum size of the fuse buffer because it is chopping off the last few characters. Is there anyway to change buf size from within my c file or does anyone know what the size of it is exactly? Thank you!

Comment: Honestly? Are you also working on this without looking at the code? If not, how do you expect us to?

Comment: Sorry, I figured out this isn't actually my problem though now. The data is being lost somewhere else. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random guess: you're using `sizeof buf` where `buf` is just a pointer (probably passed to a function), and thus getting the size of the pointer instead of the size of the memory block the pointer is pointing at. You cannot get the latter using `sizeof`, you must pass it in a separate variable.

Comment: Yes, thank you. My main problem lies elsewhere, but this was a very silly oversight.